# list `__hash__` exist although list is unhashable

Tags: python

A `list` is unhashable, so are mutables.

Then, why does `list` integrate a `__hash__` method returning `None`? Just for `hash()` call to not raise a "method does not exist exception" ?

Why simply not implementing `__hash__` method at all ?

```
"__hash__" in dir(list) # returns True
print(liste.__hash__) # returns None
```

Thanks for enlightening me on the internals !

Comment: `"A class that overrides __eq__() and does not define __hash__() will have its __hash__() implicitly set to None."` -[Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)

Comment: `list` **does not** have a `__hash__` method that returns `None`. `list.__hash__` **is** `None`. (If it just didn't have `__hash__` at all, it would inherit `object.__hash__`, which we don't want.)